# How do I extract and save data in pop-up content to a database?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, popup

I'm using Python 3.7. I'm trying to pull data from a site with Python. The Site lists the results I'm looking for based on the keyword and security code. The listed details are displayed in the form of pop-ups. The page URL does not change when Pop-up is opened. I want to save the pop-up content to the database. I'm trying them using Python-Selenium or Python-Scrapy, I've been dealing with this problem for a long time, so far I haven't succeeded. Is there a way to do this? I know this is a general question, but I'm more of a beginner. I would appreciate a sample and advice you could give me.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the series of steps.

1. Using Selenium you can switch the control to Pop-up / Alert and then read the data in the pop-up.

Sample code snippet for switching to Pop-up/alert and read the data in Java.

```
    try {
            Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert();
            log.info("Alert available");
            String text = a.getText();
            log.info(text);

        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            // Ignore
            log.info("Alert not available");            
        }
```

2. Sort the data got in above step and Connect to DB using jdbc in case of java and push the data to DB

Comment: I'm not using Java, I'm using python. Can I do this with python?